# Non-Linear System of uniform distributions. Determine the Density functions.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, conditional-expectation

Consider the non-linear system:
$$
Z = -X + W\\
Y = X + XV.
$$
Where $X$, $V$ and $W$ are mutually independent and all are $\sim U(0,1)$.

I have got some problems finding the distributions of the given exercises.

**First**: Determine the distribution of $Z$.
$$
P(Z\leq z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(P_W(z+s)\right)f_X(s)ds
$$
Now I know that I have to watch out with the boundaries, since 
$$
\begin{align}
P_W(q) &= 0,\quad q < 0\\
P_W(q) &= q,\quad q \in[0,1]\\
P_W(q) &= 1,\quad q>1.
\end{align}
$$
So $f_Z(z) = \frac{d}{dz}\int_{-z}^{1-z}\left(P_W(z+s)\right)f_X(s)ds = 1$ if $z\in[0,1]$, with help of Leibniz. Furthermore, $F_Z(z) = -1$ if $z\in[-1,0]$ and $0$ elsewhere. **Is this correct?**

**Second**: I have to find $E[Z|Y]$. I thought of finding it the following way:
$$
E[Z|Y] = E[-X + W|Y] = E[-X|Y] + E[W]\text{ since white noise and independence}\\
=E[-X|Y = y] + \frac{1}{2} = -\int_{}^{} x\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}dx + \frac{1}{2}.
$$

**Edit**:
Thank you @Did for the explanation, I too was lost in my own calculations.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Usually, white noise implies V,W are normally distributed with mean zero.

Comment: I know, but that is what the exercise said. On the other hand it does imply that $V$ is independent of $Y$ too, or am I very wrong? Also another fault of the exercise is, it said linear.

Comment: Well the problem already told you that they were all mutually independent, so yes. Ill see if I can offer a solution assuming that V,W are uniform, as stated.\

Comment: Indeed these two questions are unrelated. The argument that $E(Z\mid Y)=E(X\mid Y)+1/2$ is correct. After that, you should find that $E(X\mid Y)=u(Y)$ where $$u(y)=y/(2\log2)$$ for every $y$ in $(0,1)$ and $$u(y)=(2-y)/(2\log(2/y))$$ for every $y$ in $(1,2)$.

Comment: @Did could you explain how you got that? I tried for myself in the edit, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I got lost in your computations... As usual, things become crystal clear if one starts from the right objects, here the joint density of $(X,Y)$ is $f_{X,Y}$ defined by $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=x^{-1}\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}\mathbf 1_{x<y<2x}.$$ *Note the indicator functions, without them this is not the PDF and the rest of the proof would be messy.* Thus, $$f_Y(y)=\mathbf 1_{0<y<2}\int_{y/2}^{\min\{1,y\}}x^{-1}dx,$$ that is $$f_Y(y)=\mathbf 1_{0<y<1}\log2+\mathbf 1_{1<y<2}\log(2/y).$$ If, say, $y$ is in $(1,2)$, this yields $$E(X\mid Y=y)=(\log(2/y))^{-1}\int_{y/2}^1x\,x^{-1}dx=\ldots$$

Comment: I am quite sure the question is answered, but I can't vote up an answer or anything.